How to get video tag source file from input in HTML
I have a HLS encrypted video consisting of a playlist file (namely stream.m3u8) and a key file (namely stream.m3u8.key) and some stream.ts files. I use code below (https://hlsbook.net/playing-hls-video-in-the-browser-part-2/) to play it in a web player and it works fine
<head>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="example-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
       <source src="./stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    </video>
    <script>
        var player = videojs('example-video');
    </script>
</body>

Now I want to get source file (./stream.m3u8) from an input tag in HTML (instead of the path defined inside code). What I tried is below but it does not work.
<html>
    
    <head>
        <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <label for="input">Choose a video file to process:</label>
        <input type="file" id="input" name="input_video">
        <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="240" controls style="display: none;"></video>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
          var media = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
          var video = document.getElementById("video");
          video.src = media;
          video.style.display = "block";
          video.play();
        });

        var player = videojs('video');
    </script>

</html>

What is the wrong?

What is the wrong? I'd say it does not work. - could you add some actual details. What troubleshooting have you tried? What errors do you observe ... etc

@JaromandaX black screen without any video play. No errors, just not play anything. I believe that I could not define the file for code correctly.

What troubleshooting have you done? Add any console.log to see what the code is doing? or better still debug your code using the debugger available in any browser

@JaromandaX I used <p id="demo"></p> and document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = media;  for every java variables but no one are defined, no output.

adding a video file as the innerHTML for a <p>? java variables? what java?

Move the reference to the video element outside the event handler.
<script>
    var video = document.getElementById("video");

    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
      var media = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
      video.src = media;
      video.style.display = "block";
      video.play();
    });

    var player = videojs('video');
</script>


thank you for answer but believe me this did not work for me !!! no errors but no play window ! I mean not black screen, the play screen did not start.

I tried on firefox and chrome should I install any extension on my browser?

I have tried with your code and find the problem: video id changed

So, you have to change this line in your code too
var video = document.getElementById("video_html5_api");

edit:
the anwser that putting var video = document.getElementById("video"); outside the listener work fine too
